# Insulation when connecting a (TO-92) sensor with a cable

Tags: sensor, insulation, 1-wire

I'm considering using a DS18B20 which comes in a TO-92 package, but I have to place the sensor at a distance from the rest of the electronics so I'll have to use a wire to connect it.

However due to that the DS18B20 will be attached to a stainless steel container the pins would probably need to be insulated. Perhaps it would be a good idea to make sure that the pins are individually insulated in case a pin get bent and gets into contact with another pin.

Is it normal/kosher to use these kind of packages in this way? And what are proper ways to avoid short circuits when connecting the sensor this way?

Comment: Depending on how serious you are, anything from heatshrink to potting compounds with actual specifications, to realizing that you can buy that sensor *already* cabled and embedded in a stainless probe.  Do give due caution to random online vendors however.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Well, I've seen that there are those cabled sensors as well. The first I came across had only 1m cable which don't fit my requirement, but I've seen longer. However this solution might be more expensive, also for other sensors this solution might not be available. The idea of using a potting compound is tempting, especially as I am attaching the sensor on the container (if the potting compound could act as glue as well).